# How do I post an image if I don't have enough reputation points to do so?

Tags: discussion, new-users, images

I am new in superuser. I knew this site from my friend and I wanted to post a question. My problem is related with Google Chrome display. However, I cannot post the image since I don't have any reputation. It is hard for me to explain my problem without picture. It said that I need at least 10 points to be able to post images. Any idea how to get reputation?
Please help me as I need these bugs to be cleared as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: post a question, link the image. Someone with higher rep will be around to edit in the images

Comment: Use  www.tinypic.com   it's called image hosting.

Comment: Use imgur.com it rocks

Comment: @barlop Using third party image hosting is not encouraged. Images embedded using the post editor via stack.imgur will be kept forever.

Comment: @slhck  I often click the upload button then give it a URL from tinyurl and I think maybe the image then gets hosted on stack overflow I don't recall.. But in addition to that, this guy claims he can't post an image, so if that's true, then he can at least include a link to one from a third party site.

Comment: He's getting the following error: `Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: - We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.`

Answer (score 14):

When you write your question, just include the http link to the image, and add a comment requesting a high rep user links it for you.

Hopefully you will have enough rep to do this yourself very soon.

As regards how to get reputation, read [the reputation section](https://superuser.com/faq#reputation) of the faq.

Comment: @davidsinjaya you've read this and you still haven't included a link.